# Calling SetState() to Update UI in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an app and I'm having trouble calling setState to update my user interface.

I want to update the screen when the buttons change. So I add 2 boolean values **_local** and **_today** to change it when the button is tapped.

I'm calling the **statusGridViewer** and passing the boolean values and In the StatusGridViewer component but now  I'm unable to access the boolean values inside the build widget even after declaring them in the constructor. I've attached a image for reference.
Any Help would be grateful, Thank you.

[1](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4cGQ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4cGQ.png

StatusScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:bubble_tab_indicator/bubble_tab_indicator.dart';

import 'package:Health_app/data/covidData.dart';
import 'package:Health_app/data/data.dart';


import 'package:Health_app/screens/covidBarChart.dart';


import 'package:Health_app/config/palatte.dart';
import 'package:Health_app/config/styles.dart';

import 'package:Health_app/widgets/custom_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:Health_app/widgets/statusGridViewer.dart';[enter image description here][1]

class StatusScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StatusScreenState createState() => _StatusScreenState();
}

class _StatusScreenState extends State<StatusScreen> {
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  var _local = false;
  var _today = false;

   get local {
    return _local;
  }

     get today {
    return _today;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print("Didchangedependanciescalled");
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<CovidData>(context, listen: true)
          .fetchAndSetDataCovid()
          .then((_) => {
                setState(() {
                  _isLoading = false;
                }),
              });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Palette.primaryColor,
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : CustomScrollView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              slivers: [
                _buildHeader(),
                _buildRegionTabBar(),
                _buildStateTabBar(),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: StatusGridViewer(local,today),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: CovidBarChart(
                      covidCases: covidDailyCases,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  SliverPadding _buildHeader() {
    return SliverPadding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Statistics',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  SliverToBoxAdapter _buildRegionTabBar() {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white24,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            indicator: BubbleTabIndicator(
              tabBarIndicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicatorHeight: 40.0,
              indicatorColor: Colors.white60,
            ),
            labelStyle: Styles.tabTextStyle,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: [
              Text('Local'),
              Text('Global'),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              print('Statmeaer changed ' + index.toString());
             
                if (index.isOdd) {
                  _local = !_local;
                }
             
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  SliverPadding _buildStateTabBar() {
    return SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            labelStyle: Styles.tabTextStyle,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white54,
            tabs: [
              Text('Today'),
              Text('Total'),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              print('Date to show details selected ' + index.toString());
              if (index.isOdd) {
                _today = !_today;
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

StateGrid component

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    
    import '../data/covidData.dart';
    
    
    class StatusGridViewer extends StatefulWidget {
    
      final bool localData;
      final bool todayData;
    
      StatusGridViewer(this.localData, this.todayData);
    
      @override
      _StatusGridViewerState createState() => _StatusGridViewerState();
    }
    
    class _StatusGridViewerState extends State<StatusGridViewer> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        final covidData = Provider.of<CovidData>(context);
        final dataInstance = covidData.data;
    
        
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
          color: Colors.white24,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    
                    _buildStateCard("Total Cases", "count", Colors.yellow),
                    _buildStateCard("Total Deaths", "countDeath", Colors.red),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    _buildStateCard("Total Recovered", "countRec", Colors.green),
                    _buildStateCard("Total Active", "countAct", Colors.grey),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Expanded _buildStateCard(String name, String patCount, MaterialColor color) {
        return Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  patCount,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `widget.boolenName`

```
widget.localData
//Not localData, because it's a stateful widget.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is basically two concepts you should be considering in your code.

The first one, as mentioned in an answer before mine is that whenever you declare variables in a `stateful widget`, your `state class` which extends the stateful class can only access the variables in the constructor by calling `widget.variable`.
In this case you should be using `widget.localData/todayData` instead of `localData/todayData`.

The second one is about state management. Since your `StatusGridViewer` is a direct child of your main page, you should use `setState()` in your main page every time one of the bool values changes in order to reconstruct your child page. Otherwise, even though internally the variables would have indeed changed, it would not reflect on your UI.

Nevertheless, you should opt for a state management solution other than setState itself, since most of the times there is a specific block of UI you want to update.
Here are some options:

- https://pub.dev/packages/bloc
- https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Thank you Spots Solutions, Really helpfull Answer. I wanted to fetch data from an API and update it on my screen. I manage to store data in a local variable and wrap the application with the changeNotifierProvider and display them on the screen altering the boolean values